# show/hide textbox if comboxbox is null or not

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, null, textbox

first of all i want to say thanks for every person who respond me for my previous quesiton,
i have a combobox (list) and a textbox(key1), but i want to enable textbox IF combobox is not null, I tried to to this by this code

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If IsNullOrEmpty(ComboBox1.Text) Then

TextBox1.Visible = False
TextBox1.Enabled = False


Else
TextBox1.Visible = True
TextBox1.Enabled = True
End If


End Sub
```

but the result is always the textbox1 is disabled, even if i choose from the list or combobox<>null

Comment: Please use the editing tool to include images - don't post links to outside sources. You might also want to include a link to the Stack Overflow discussion you reference in the question if that contains important background information. The [edit] link below the question enables you to change its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler than you are making it.

Instead, test for the length of the ComboBox1's text property being greater than 0. That will give you a boolean value of True/False. You can then use that boolean result to set any other boolean value property (like the `Enabled` or `Visible` property) all in one line.

Also, you need to put it on the `Change` event of `ComboBox1`, not `TextBox1`.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  TextBox1.Enabled = (Len(ComboBox1.Text)>0)
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  TextBox1.Visible = (Len(ComboBox1.Text)>0)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your help but It's not work, even if I choose from combobox, the textbox is still not visible

Comment: I assumed you would know how to put it on the right event, but ok, i updated the answer.